# Problem with create UITableViewCell custom cell with progress view each cell

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitableview, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

Image 1

After scroll down and up. progress bar blank ??

Image 2

1. Custom cell for each cell and download via urlsession.

   ```
   ## custom cell
   class chattingCustomCell: UITableViewCell {



   var downloadCustomTask:URLSessionDownloadTask!
    lazy var progressView : UIProgressView = {

    let progress = UIProgressView.init()
    progress.tintColor = .red
    return progress
    }()



    lazy var lbProgressView : UILabel = {

    let lb = UILabel.init()
    lb.textAlignment = .center
    return lb
     }()

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
    {
            DispatchQueue.main.async{

                if totalBytesExpectedToWrite > 0 {
                    let progress = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)

                    self.progressView.progress = progress
                    self.lbProgressView.text = "\(Float(totalBytesWritten)) / \(Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite))"

                    //            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    self.appDelegate.function.loglog(methodDesc: "\(NSStringFromClass(self.classForCoder))", str: "Video download progress : \(progress) -> \(Float(totalBytesWritten))/ \(Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite))")

                    //                self.Progress.progress=progress

                    if(progress == 1)
                    {

                        self.appDelegate.function.loglog(methodDesc: "\(NSStringFromClass(self.classForCoder))", str: "Progress : done")



                    }
                    //            }

                    //            debugPrint("Progress \(downloadTask) \(progress)")
                }
            }
        }

   }
    .....



     override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)


    progressView = UIProgressView.init(frame: CGRect(x: (imageFrame.frame.size.width/2)-(150/2), y: (imageFrame.frame.size.height/2), width: 150, height: 10))
                        progressView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                        progressView.layer.zPosition = 10
                        progressView.progress = 0
                        self.imageFrame.addSubview(progressView)
                        lbProgressView = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect(x: (imageFrame.frame.size.width/2)-(150/2), y: (imageFrame.frame.size.height/2)+10, width: 150, height: 10))
                        lbProgressView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
                        lbProgressView.textAlignment = .center
                        self.imageFrame.addSubview(lbProgressView)


    }
   ```
2. if don't scroll screen it's work perfect for download video each cell with display progress status.
3. when scroll down and scroll up screen. progress view it's blank but urlsession still downloading.

how to fixed it.
Thank you for advance.

Comment: When you scroll , if download is still in progress you need to update the progress view calling some method from data view source. Having the url session in cell may not be a good idea : what happens when the cell is reused?

Comment: cuz I want to operate cell for download with progress. I try many solution. this its work. advance for me. thank

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: when cell download video first. its show progressive work fine. and after scroll down and up tableview . cell reuse and progressive it's blank and not update.